# Redirection between pages in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

how to redirect between pages..for eg.if i click on login link then it should be redirect on login page..

Answer (score 3):

If your question is about:

1. *Generating* a url for page associated to your application, then I recommend checking out the [Url view-helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html).
2. *Displaying* a url, then I recommend checking out [view-scripts](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html) and [layouts](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.html).
3. *Redirecting* to a url - say, from within a controller, after successful login - then I recommend checking out the [Redirector action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure I understand your question....

If you want to create a link on a page to a controller / action, for example if your login script was in the controller `users` and the action was called `login`, you could put a link in the view script of a page by using the [`baseUrl`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html):

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl("users/login"); ?>">Login</a>
```